# $x_{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}|x_n+x_{n-1}|$ Prove that there exists a sub-sequence of $(x)_n$ that converges to $0$, nomatter how we choose $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that:
$x_{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}|x_n+x_{n-1}|$ $ \forall n \in \Bbb N^*$.

Prove that there exists a sub-sequence of $(x)_n$ that converges to $0$, nomatter how we choose $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Comment: Series (an infinite sum)? Or sequence?

Comment: Sequence, as in a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried setting $x_0$ and $x_1$ as positives and build the sequence from there, and i also tried looking at only the positive terms in the sequence (basically de absolute value of the sequence), but i wasn't able to reach a useful conclusion.